# Attribute routing not working and throwing 404 error in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I applied Attribute routing to my RouteConfig.cs and added [Route("Store")] attribute on Action but getting error when access the url.

Working URL is http://localhost:52859/shop/store/dominos

I want it to change to http://localhost:52859/store/dominos

But post updating Attribute routing I see error on page as

Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

and in URL it shows as

http://localhost:52859/Errors/Error404?aspxerrorpath=/shop/store/dominos

Updated in RouteConfig

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Action to call Stores

```
// GET: /shop/category/name
        [Route("Store")]
        public ActionResult Store(string name)
        {
            // Declare a list of Coupons
            List<Coupn> coupnList;


            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {

                // Get store id
                Store storeDTO = db.Store.Where(x => x.Slug == name).FirstOrDefault();
                int storeId = storeDTO.StoreID;
                ViewBag.TopDesc = storeDTO.TopDesc;
                ViewBag.MainDesc = storeDTO.MainDesc;
                ViewBag.StoreLogo = storeDTO.StoreLogo;
                ViewBag.StoreName = storeDTO.StoreName;


                // Init the list
                coupnList = db.Coupns.ToArray().Where(x => x.StoreID == storeId).ToList();

                // Get Store     name
                var coupnStore = db.Coupns.Where(x => x.StoreID == storeId).FirstOrDefault();
                ViewBag.StoreName = coupnStore.StoreName;

            }

            // Return view with list
            return View(coupnList);
        }
```

Help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `Route` like `[Route("~/[action]/{name}")]`.

Check this to get more details about Routing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis

Your `action` will look like below.

```
[Route("~/[action]/{name}")]
public ActionResult Store(string name)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Good with this method

Comment: Thank you Karan for clarification on this. Does work as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the route at the `Controller` level for the URL you want to use to work and set the `action` route to `"{name}"`. Like this:

```
[Route("Store")]
public class StoreController: Controller
{
    // GET: /store/name
    [Route("{name}")]
    public ActionResult Store(string name)
    {
        // Declare a list of Coupons
        List<Coupn> coupnList;


        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {

            // Get store id
            Store storeDTO = db.Store.Where(x => x.Slug == name).FirstOrDefault();
            int storeId = storeDTO.StoreID;
            ViewBag.TopDesc = storeDTO.TopDesc;
            ViewBag.MainDesc = storeDTO.MainDesc;
            ViewBag.StoreLogo = storeDTO.StoreLogo;
            ViewBag.StoreName = storeDTO.StoreName;


            // Init the list
            coupnList = db.Coupns.ToArray().Where(x => x.StoreID == storeId).ToList();

            // Get Store     name
            var coupnStore = db.Coupns.Where(x => x.StoreID == storeId).FirstOrDefault();
            ViewBag.StoreName = coupnStore.StoreName;

        }

        // Return view with list
        return View(coupnList);
    }
}
```

If you are working on `ASP.NET MVC` make sure to activate Routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If you are working on `.Net Core`:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IWebHostEnvironment env
)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I just tried but got similar error..http://localhost:52859/Errors/Error404?aspxerrorpath=/store/dominos

Comment: You may have some configuration issues, check my update.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for making it easy to understand. Works like a charm :D

Comment: Glad it was of help. Happy coding!

Comment: @Riyaz If you want your `route` to be like `/ActionName/{ParamVaue}` then this might be incorrect. In this case it might work because your `action name` & `controller name` are same. If you are having one more `action` like `public ActionResult Xyz(string name)` and you add `[Route("{name}")]` for it then it will throw exception.

Comment: I like this way

Comment: True, I agree, I have another Action name as Category, which is giving an error when try to access for that Category. How can this be fixed?

Comment: In same Controller I have another ActionName public ActionResult Category(string name) but when applying this solution throws an error when try accessing Category Actionname.

Comment: @Riyaz Once you use `Route` in the controller, you need to apply it to all the actions to work. In the case Karan pointed out, for that route to work you need to apply `[Route("Xyz/{name}")]`

Comment: Thank you again, updated and is now working for other Action too